# Matplotlib giving wrong tick label values when figure size is changed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the following code to plot a matplotlib stack plot:

```
mpl.rcdefaults()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
years = [1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020]
data = [
    [10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 11000], [20000, 21000, 31000, 61000, 65000],
    [0, 10000, 30000, 100000, 90000]]

 ax.stackplot(years, data)

ax.grid(linestyle='--', color='k', alpha=0.15, axis='y')
ax.set_yticklabels([x / 1000 for x in ax.get_yticks()])

width = 6
height = width/1.6

fig.set_size_inches(width, height)
```

This creates the following chart, with the correct y axis labels:
[image: stackplot]

However, when I change the size of the plot with `width = 4`, I get the following chart, where the y tick values seem to have halved for some reason:

[image: stack plot with the y tick labels showing half the value they should be]

What gives?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact that after resizing the `yticks` are different and hence you get the larger set of labels that does not really fit accordingly. You need to set the labels after resizing. As you can see, the resized plot only has four ticks. The first four ticklabels from plot before resizing are shown in your output, which are not correct.

Just for the sake of explanation, I have kept the `print()` for `tick` and `ticklabels` before and after resizing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcdefaults()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

years = [1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020]
data = [
    [10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 11000], [20000, 21000, 31000, 61000, 65000],
    [0, 10000, 30000, 100000, 90000]]

ax.stackplot(years, data)
ax.grid(linestyle='--', color='k', alpha=0.15, axis='y')
print("Ticks before:",list(ax.get_yticks()))
width = 4
height = width/1.6
fig.set_size_inches(width, height)
ax.set_yticklabels([x/1000 for x in ax.get_yticks()])
print("Ticks after:",list(ax.get_yticks()))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oops - I had a typo in my question. That line should actually read: `ax.set_yticklabels([x / 1000 for x in ax.get_yticks()])`, and so is relevant to format the y axis numbers.